# Wordpress pagination, not show some content on numbered pages

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a news site in Wordpress.

The news stories are all posts.

The home page has a promotional section at the top and then a list of the stories.

There is pagination at the bottom to show the rest of the stories on another page.

On the pages after the home page I don't want to show the promotional section.

The home page has a url like

```
    mysite.co.uk/news
```

and the second page is like

```
    mysite.co.uk/news//page/2
```

(I don't know why there are two foward slashes after 'news')

I tried using an if statment on the is_page but it doesn't work.

```
    <?php 

        if(is_page('News')){
    ?>

        <div class="news-content-block">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="news-content-block__header">

                    <div class="row">

                        <?php 

                            $news_intro = array(

                                'category_name' => 'news',
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                'orderby' => 'date',
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                                'posts_per_page' => 2
                            );

                            $news_loop = new WP_Query($news_intro);

                            if($news_loop->have_posts()) :
                                while($news_loop->have_posts()) :
                                    $news_loop->the_post();
                        ?>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="news-article-block">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('news_header', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ), true); ?>
                                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                    </div><!--row-->

                </div>

            </div><!--container-->

        </div><!--content-block-->

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

How do I only show the promotional things on the news home page

Comment: pagnation dispalying or not  ??

Comment: pagination should display on all pages if there are more pages. It's the promotional section on the home page I don't want to show on the other pages

Comment: do you want  to try my working code

Comment: Yes if i can, I'l try your code

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your page template

```
if ( !isset($wp_query->query_vars['paged']) || $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] == 1 ) :
# Featured post code
endif;
```

Comment: Is '# Featured post code' the promotional section i want to hide on the pages that isn't the home page.Thats what I've tried but it doesn't show it on any page.

Comment: with this code the featured post only shows for first page

Answer (score 0):

Use [`is_paged()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged) function: it will return true if the current page number is greater than one (so it will return false for the home page, then true for page 2, 3 etc).

```
if(is_paged()):
  // feature code...
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Working Code :**

> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=video_comment&paged=2
>   `$_REQUEST['paged']` value get from url

```
    $paged = (!isset($_REQUEST['paged']) ? '1' : $_REQUEST['paged'] );
$args = array (
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'search_prod_title' => $search_term,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?><?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?><?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 

$current_stat= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'vc_stat');

if(isset($current_stat[0]))
{
    if($current_stat[0]=='1')
    {
         $status='<label class="label label-success">Active</label>';
    }
    else
    {
         $status='<label class="label label-danger">Inactive</label>';
    }
}else
{
      $status='<label class="label label-success">Active</label>';
}

?>
               <tr>
                  <td width="20%" id=""><?php the_title(); ?><input type="hidden" id="postID" value="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>">
                   <input type="hidden" id="parmalink" value="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                   </td>

                  <td width="70%">

                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success view_vc" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Comments</button>

                </td>
                <td width="5%" id="status"><?php _e($status);?></td>
                  <td width="5%"><select class="action">
                      <option>-Select-</option>
                      <option value="1" >Active</option>
                      <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>


<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]